# How to remove Fragment from an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to remove a fragment from my MainActivity after clicking a choice in the slide menu. But I cannot find how to implement it.

I looked online and found the `FragmentTransaction` class but I think I have the wrong implementation.

MainActivity Java;

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.Technology) {
            FragmentTransaction.remove(R.layout.frag);


        } else if (id == R.id.Opinion) {


        } else if (id == R.id.travel) {

        } else if (id == R.id.politics) {

        }else if(id == R.id.Home){
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
```

XML file for the main_content;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#692f2f"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/frag" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my english.

If you want to be able to manage your fragments at runtime, you should not hard code them in your XML file instead put an empty container in your XML like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        />
```

You would normally not want to use `wrap_content` for both the layout_width and layout_height to make the placement easier. Also the margin can go directly on the content of the fragment rather than the fragment itself otherwise, you can put it back in the main_activity XML layout file.

and have inflate it in your fragment class:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout_here, container, null);
    }
```

Then in your code, you should have a FragmentManager to use a FragmentTransaction , for example:

```
private FragmentManager fm;
private FragmentTransaction ft
```

in the `onCreate` function :

```
fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Then :

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.Technology) {
            ft.remove (fragment_instance_to_remove_here);
            ft.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.Opinion) {


        } else if (id == R.id.travel) {

        } else if (id == R.id.politics) {

        }else if(id == R.id.Home){
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

For more explanations [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) .

Hope it's help.

Comment: It's giving me that ft.remove cannot be applied to int.

Comment: ft.remove() take the instance of your fragment, not the layout, my mistake look @Falla Coulibaly edit.

Comment: @asdddd if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.